# How to Update Flake8 Settings in VSCode Following Deprecation Warning

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, flake8

I've always been modifying my Flake8 settings through a file named 'settings.json' located inside the .vscode folder. This file is automatically generated when you choose a linter.

However, for the past few weeks, I've been receiving a warning from VSCode that says:
"This setting will soon be deprecated. Please use the Flake8 extension. Learn more here: https://aka.ms/AAlgvkb ."

From the provided link, I understand that Flake8 should be used as an extension, but it doesn't explain how to modify settings in another way.

Here's an example of my 'settings.json' file:

```
{
    "python.linting.flake8Enabled": true,
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "python.linting.flake8Args": [
        "--max-line-length=120"
    ]
}
```

Comment: related: [Why does the VS Code Python extension (circa v2018.19) no longer provide support for several Python tools like linters and formatters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77283648/11107541)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this setting, more configuration information here.

*https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-flake8#settings*

```json
    "flake8.args": [
        "--max-line-length=120"
    ],
```

[image]